# Cast from Object to Map<String, Long> in Java

Tags: java

I have implemented a method which returns a `CompletableFuture<Object>` and inside the method, I use a `Map<String, Long>` and this is the object which I return and the cast is done automatically.

Next, I want to use the result of this method for another function and inside the new function, I need to deserialize the Object into the `Map<String, Long>`. Is it possible to make a normal cast or should I do something different?

```
@Override
    public CompletableFuture<Boolean> process(String name, Object data, Object message) {

        switch (name) {
            case ("first"):

                Map<String, Long> finalAmount = (Map<String, Long>) data;
```

Is this way of doing the cast right?

Comment: The cast is correct but why do you use a `CompletableFuture<Object>` in the first place instead of a `CompletableFuture<Map<String, Long>>`?

Comment: because that function might use also other types of Collections, not only Map...so this is why I made it as general as possible

Comment: The cast is fine, but why don't you make the method creating the CompletableFuture genericized so it returns exactly the type you need?

Comment: For the specific case that `Object data` transfers the type `Map <String, Long>` the cast will work in your code example. In this case you could also pass `Map <String, Long> data` directly, which would make the cast unnecessary. For a general solution that passes a different type, the cast would fail. So you would have to check the type before the cast.